# is it possible to send 0x00 in GET request?

Tags: php, hex, urlrequest

I want to send hex data as GET request like somesite.com/page.php?test=hex_string.
The data is generated data in hardware and then a GET request is send to a php file.

But when I have **0x00 (NULL)** character in the request, it fails with 400 bad request message.

Is there a way I could send NUL character in GET request?

Comment: Nothing stops `0x00` from being sent in an HTTP request. `https://www.google.com/?q=0x00`

Comment: I know that's what I thought. But when I remove 0x00 from my data string, PHP page receives the data correctly

Comment: That almost certainly means that the specific webserver in question doesn't like that value there

Comment: So only I ask this question to know if there is a possible solution

Comment: What is the hardware, and how does it generate the get request?

Comment: I've never done this kind of thing before, but I would try to convert to base64 before sending and back to hex after receiving. That is if I am able to control the receiving application. But otherwise no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `/?hexdecimal_nullbyte=%00`

It fails because web server on the other side prevents [`null-byte attacks`](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte). So, the web server says you it's a `400 bad request`, don't do this :)

Comment: I am sending data from hardware and there everything is handled in hex so can't avoid this!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before.
The only solution I found is to convert those null bytes as a decimal before **page.php** reads it, then in that **page.php** I convert it back to byte before sending it to the hardware.